# Generate dpkg .deb filename

Tags: debian, dpkg

We have a software project, which we release as a debian package. The project has a debian/ folder which contains files like `changelog  compat  control  copyright  rules`. We're creating debian packages with the command:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b --changes-option=-u./dist
```

which prints a stream of output. What we need to know, for the next step of the process, is the name of the .deb file created.

I know that debians have a predictable filename structure like `[package name]_[version]_[architecture].deb` but I don't have a way to get these parameters anyway.

There must be another dpkg command that can generate the would-be package name just from looking in the debian folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you point out, the generated `.deb` files all share a common format: `${package}_${version}_${arch}.deb`.

The package name comes from the `Package:` entries in `debian/control`; for a full build, one `.deb` file will be generated for every `Package:` entry. You can retrieve the values with

```
awk '/^Package:/ { print $2 }' debian/control
```

The version is based by default on the value given in debian/changelog; you can extract that with

```
dpkg-parsechangelog -S version
```

(It is possible for a build to specify a different version, but that is unusual.)

Finally, the architecture will be either `all` (for an `Architecture: all` package) or by default that of your build system (for any other `Architecture:`, typically `Architecture: any`). You can determine the architecture of your build system using

```
dpkg-architecture -qDEB_BUILD_ARCH
```

(Strictly speaking that should be `-qDEB_HOST_ARCH`, but in the general case `BUILD` and `HOST` are the same. I'm also ignoring cross-compilation here; if that's an issue use `DEB_TARGET_ARCH` instead of `DEB_BUILD_ARCH`.)

Thus for a fully generic solution you'd need to parse the `control` file to determine which package goes with which architecture; if your `control` file only builds one package that's not necessary.

`dpkg-parsechangelog` and `dpkg-architecture` are provided by the `dpkg-dev` package.

Comment: Seems weird there isn't a single command to do this in 1 step. But I'm grateful for your answer, and will try this out asap.

Comment: You're a star @stephen-kitt :
`$ echo "$(awk '/^Package:/ { print $2 }' debian/control)_$(dpkg-parsechangelog --show-field version)_$(dpkg-architecture -qDEB_BUILD_ARCH).deb"`
`mypackage_3.8.2_amd64.deb`

Comment: To get the package name by itself could you also not simply do `dpkg-parsechangelog -S Source` ?

Comment: @Nicholi that gives you the source package name, but here we’re looking for all the binary package names. For simple packages there will only be one binary package with the same name as the source package, but that’s not always the case.

Comment: Gotcha, which generally would be the same but no guarantee.

Comment: @Nicholi I’m not sure about “generally”; for my packages it’s just over 50% of the time.

Comment: Without testing looks to me that this may have a problem. On macOS/homebrew the output from dpkg seems to conform to ${package}_${version}_${arch}.deb but on Ubuntu it seems to be ${package}_${version}-1_${arch}.deb. Note the '-1'  which I guess is 'devian revision'. So parsing from the control file version may in certain scenarious (like mine) be problematic.

Comment: @nyholku `dpkg-parsechangelog -S version` shows the full version, including Debian revision. Native packages don’t have a revision, which might explain the difference you’re seeing.

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks. I managed to solve my issues without parsing so I'm good, but good to know. I thought I'd just mention this little quirk I came across. I'm un-packaging and re-packing a .deb package produced by Java jlink to do some surgery on the package and my tool worked on Linux but not on macOS or vice versa because I assumed the file/version format. Now I just re-use the original package name so all is good.

Answer (score 3):

This is [dpkg-name](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dpkg-name.1.html):

```
$dpkg-name foo.deb
dpkg-name: info: moved 'foo.deb' to './feature-dev_1.4.177_armhf.deb'
```

Original name `foo` taken from DEBIAN/ directory parent